# Using variables with localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization

```
 MyResources.LocalizedText.Option1
```

I'm using localization on one of my web pages. As an example, when I want to display a text based on the page culture, I use the above code.

So far so good. Now I want to get the localizedText based on a variable as follows:

```
var option = "Option1",
MyResources.LocalizedText. //here I want to have the value of the variable option (which in this case is Option1).
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
MyResources.LocalizedText.ResourceManager.GetString(option, MyResources.LocalizedText.Culture)
```

or

```
MyResources.LocalizedText.ResourceManager.GetString(option)
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for description of .GetString method.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly well with MyResources.LocalizedText.ResourceManager.GetString(option)